# Check if a column value for a table is null or not

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am getting count of rows for all tables in my database in the below manner.

```
public Map<String,Long> getGpTableCount() throws SQLException {
    Map<String, String> gpTableMap = getScopeTableList();
    Set<String> gpTableSet = gpTableMap.keySet();       // Gets all table names
    gpCountMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    Iterator<String> keySetIterator_gpTables = gpTableSet.iterator();
    Connection gpAnalyticsCon = (Connection) DbManager.getGpConnection();
    while(keySetIterator_gpTables.hasNext()) {
        String gpSchemaTableName = keySetIterator_gpTables.next();  // Ex: dbname.tablename
        String[] gpparts = gpSchemaTableName.split("\\.");  // dbname, tablename
        String gpTable = gpparts[1];
        String gpCountQuery = "select '" + gpTable + "' as TableName, count(*) as Count, source_system_name from " + gpSchemaTableName + " group by source_system_name order by source_system_name";
        // resultSet(1): TableName, resultSet(2): count, resultSet(3): source_system_name
        try {
            PreparedStatement gp_pstmnt = gpAnalyticsCon.prepareStatement(gpCountQuery);
            ResultSet gpCountRs = gp_pstmnt.executeQuery();
            while(gpCountRs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Tablename: " + gpCountRs.getString(1) + " Source System Name: " + gpCountRs.getString(3) + ", Count: " + gpCountRs.getLong(2));
                gpCountMap.put(gpTable + ": " + gpCountRs.getString(3), gpCountRs.getLong(2));
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Table: " + gpTable + " not found on GP for the source system: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    gpAnalyticsCon.close();
    return gpCountMap;
}
```

The problem I am facing here is that if I want to get the count for particular source_system_name and change the query to               `String gpCountQuery = "select '" + gpTable + "' as TableName, count(*) as Count, source_system_name from " + gpSchemaTableName + " where source_system_name in ('ABCD','EFGH') group by source_system_name order by source_system_name";`

for some tables, there is no value in the column 'source_system_name' and I am getting column "source_system_name" does not exist exception which can be seen below.

```
Table: some_table_name not found on GP for the source system:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "source_system_name" does not exist
  Position: 64
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:116)
        at com.recordcount.dao.GpHiveRecords.getGpTableCount(GpHiveRecords.java:69)
```

I have given the source_system_name in the query's 'in' clause directly.
Since there is not check before executing the query, it results in exception.

Could anyone let me know how can I add a condition in the code before executing the count query to check if the table contains the value of given source_system_name and only if it exists, get the count of it.

Comment: Check the query you are executing is correctly created (log it at some point or debug the code). Then check if it runs on your db using any DB client. PS: careful to SQL Injection a query build like this.

Comment: Try adding schema name before the table name and check once

Comment: You are passing gpSchemaTableName  as dynamic parameter, So we are not guarantee whether the column exists or not. If you want to know about that first execute normal select statement with dynamic table name and get the metadata and then check is the column exists or not then build your actual query.